# parsing arguments in overloading in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace midq6
{
    class Program
    {
        const double pi=3.142;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program test = new Program();
            test.area(2.0,2.8,4.0,4.9,5.0,3.8);        
        }

    public double area(double s) 
    {
        double area = s * s;
        Console.WriteLine("Area of a square: "+ area);
        return area;
    }
    public double area(double l, double w) 
    {
        double area = l * w;
        Console.WriteLine("Area of a rectengle: "+ area);
        return area;
    }
    public double area(double h,double b) 
    {
        double area = 0.5 * h * b;
        Console.WriteLine("Area of a triangle: " + area);
        return area;
    }
    public double area(double r) 
    {
        double area = pi * r * r;
        return area;
    }

    }
}
```

that's my code for overloading, its giving me error when um giving it arguments in my main method...can guys please help

Comment: What is the error _exactly_? Can you please be more specific about your problem?

Comment: this code should not compile. if you read the error message carefully, and if required, search for explanations of it with a search engine, i am sure you can find out what the problem is. if not, try to write 4 lines of code, each one calling one of your 4 `area` methods.

Comment: [CS0111](http://www.bing.com/search?q=CS0111++C%23+Type+%27%27+already+defines+a+member+called+%27%27+with+the+same+parameter+types&form=VSHELP)?

Comment: How is method signature `public double area(double s)`  different from `double area(double r)`? Do you think this is right?

Comment: it says: no overload for method 'area' takes six arguments...

Comment: good, did you define any method with six arguments?

Comment: @ CarbineCoder thanks ..i didn't  see that

Comment: You should be using an OOP method instead of overloading, see how MS do the polymorphic shape area method here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Overloaded methods must have unique method signatures, specifically each overload must have different parameters.

You are declaring two `area(double)` methods and two `area(double,double)` methods. This is invalid overloading, thus the code won't compile.

If the code did compile and I called `area(4.0)`, which of the rectangle and circle methods should be called? There's no way for the compiler and runtime to know which one you mean. That's why there is the signature restriction on overloading.

Your method names are really unclear though and this is a bad use of overloading. Call the methods `AreaOfSquare`, `AreaOfTriangle` etc. This will both fix your problem and make your code far more readable.

Comment: but David i thought to use overload it should have same method name but different order of parameters, data type,,,,so if i change the names to AreaOfSquare, AreaOfTriangle is it still going to be overloading?

Comment: It won't be overloading.  But why do you want it to be overloaded?  This is a prime example of a time when you SHOULDN'T overload.

Comment: You are right, overloading won't be used. Overloading should be used sparingly as it all too easily makes your code's intentions less clear.

Comment: i had two doubles, and my double s and double r,were read the same...so i  have fixed all that....now its running thanks David

Comment: *Overloading should be used sparingly as it all too easily makes your code's intentions less clear.* - overloads are fine more so when they call a base method allowing basic config via different arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You have two identical declarations of `double area(double, double);`.  You cannot have identical overloads.  You'll need to redesign your class.

Comment: but David i thought to use overload it should have same method name but different order of parameters, data type,,,,so if i change the names to  AreaOfSquare, AreaOfTriangle is it still going to be overloading?

Comment: Your order of parameters are not different.  They are the same.  Two doubles.  I don't think you understand what method overloading is.  Try reading the MSDN article.

Comment: yer i didn't understand overloading today in class ....i have fixed all that now its running thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

```
public double area(double s) {}
```

and

```
public double area(double r) {}
```

are same for the compiler and hence not allowed as overload. Change your function names, for instance

```
public double SquareArea(double s) {}
```

and

```
public double CircleArea(double r) {}
```

Also, you haven't defined any method which takes 6 arguments but you are calling

```
test.area(2.0,2.8,4.0,4.9,5.0,3.8);
```

which is not permitted.

If you wan't to use variadic arguments in C#, use the `params` keyword. For example

```
public double Area(params double[] args) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Addition, you are passing 6 arguments but there is no method that takes 6 arguments. If you want to be flexible at that point, declare a method that takes params:

```
public double area(params double[] s) 
{

}
```